# Animating SVG tentacles to move

Tags: animation, svg

Anyone ever had any luck animating an SVG to wave?

Fastest drawing ever: http://cl.ly/XEtd

I've got an octopus, and I want to move the arms of it, but rather than just rotating around a point somewhere, I want to move the points of the path.

Is it literally a case of just settings the points, then settings the points to the next arm position and frame by frame it in CSS?

Comment: What about the obvious solution of just making individual paths for each arm position and animating the arms by showing and hiding each of the arm paths?  Is there a reason you don't want to do it that way?

Comment: Curious, did you ever solved this? Encountering a nearly identical scenario.

Comment: Nothing at the time of this, but i would recomend using BodyMovin' – it's an after effects plugin for exporting animated SVGs

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using snap.svg, I think it's pretty easy to use it to do what you're trying to do, see this example:

[How to animate path morphs using snap.svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987836/how-to-animate-path-morphs-using-snap-svg)

If you don't want to use snap or some similar library, you might be able to look at what it produces and get an idea how to do it by hand.