# SVG path calculation results in all zeroed coordinates

Tags: jquery, svg, snap.svg

I'm playing around with making a script that would let me make a simple svg path tween (smooth morph animation) between two or more keyframes with the same number of values. The shapes I've input should morph an oval shape (keyframe[0]) to a speech bubble shape (keyframe[1]).

The problem I am experiencing is that when I try to debug, it tells me that the svg element has values all of 0.

```
<path d="M0, 0, Q0, 0, 0, 0, L0, 0, Q0, 0, 0, 0, L0, 0, Q0, 0, 0, 0, L0, 0, Q0, 0, 0, 0, L0, 0, L0, 0, L0, 0, Z" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000"></path>
```

When the console shows me that the values it *should* have are

```
M-68.39999999999999, -18.787499999999998, Q-72.9, 0, -97.2, -4.5, L-97.2, -258.525, Q-121.5, -263.02500000000003, -116.99999999999999, -281.8125, L68.39999999999999, -281.8125, Q72.9, -300.59999999999997, 97.2, -296.1, L97.2, -42.075, Q121.5, -37.574999999999996, 116.99999999999999, -18.787499999999998, L48.6, -18.787499999999998, L24.3, 18.787499999999998, L0, -18.787499999999998, ZM-70.93333333333334, -19.483333333333334, Q-75.60000000000001, 0, -100.8, -4.666666666666666, L-100.8, -268.09999999999997, Q-126, -272.76666666666665, -121.33333333333333, -292.25, L70.93333333333334, -292.25, Q75.60000000000001, -311.73333333333335, 100.8, -307.06666666666666, L100.8, -43.63333333333333, Q126, -38.96666666666667, 121.33333333333333, -19.483333333333334, L50.4, -19.483333333333334, L25.2, 19.483333333333334, L0, -19.483333333333334, Z
```

There must be an error with my logic somewhere but I'm left scratching my head as to why this doesn't work.

JS:

```
$(function() {

    var sponsorBubble = function(el, html, cornerRad) {
        this.html = html,
        this.width = el.parent().width(),
        this.height = el.parent().height(),
        this.arrowWidth = el.parent().width()/4,
        this.arrowHeight = el.parent().height()/8,
        this.cornerRad = cornerRad;


        //ENSURE SAME NUMBER OF PATH SEGMENTS IN ALL KEYFRAMES (START TO END)
        this.keypaths = [];

        this.keypaths[0] = [
            "M",
            (this.width/2) - (this.arrowWidth/2), this.height - (this.arrowHeight/2),
            "Q",
            (this.width/2) - (this.arrowWidth/2), this.height - this.arrowHeight,
            (this.width/2), this.height - this.arrowHeight,
            "L",
            (this.width/2), this.height - this.arrowHeight,
            "Q",
            (this.width/2) + (this.arrowWidth/2), this.height - this.arrowHeight,
            (this.width/2) + (this.arrowWidth/2), this.height - (this.arrowHeight/2),
            "L",
            (this.width/2) + (this.arrowWidth/2), this.height - (this.arrowHeight/2),
            "Q",
            (this.width/2) + (this.arrowWidth/2), this.height,
            (this.width/2), this.height,
            "L",
            (this.width/2), this.height,
            "Q",
            (this.width/2) - (this.arrowWidth/2), this.height,
            (this.width/2) - (this.arrowWidth/2), this.height - (this.arrowHeight/2),
            "L",
            (this.width/2) - (this.arrowWidth/2), this.height - (this.arrowHeight/2),
            "L",
            (this.width/2) - (this.arrowWidth/2), this.height - (this.arrowHeight/2),
            "L",
            (this.width/2) - (this.arrowWidth/2), this.height - (this.arrowHeight/2),
            "Z"
        ];

        this.keypaths[1] = [
            "M", //STARTS AT BOTTOM LEFT, GOING CLOCKWISE
            this.cornerRad, this.height-this.arrowHeight,
            "Q",
            0, this.height-this.arrowHeight,
            0, this.height-this.arrowHeight-this.cornerRad,
            "L",
            0, this.cornerRad,
            "Q",
            0,0,
            this.cornerRad, 0,
            "L",
            this.cornerRad+(this.width - (this.cornerRad*2)), 0,
            "Q",
            this.width, 0,
            this.width, this.cornerRad,
            "L",
            this.width, this.cornerRad+(this.height-this.arrowHeight-(this.cornerRad*2)),
            "Q",
            this.width, this.height-this.arrowHeight,
            this.width-this.cornerRad, this.height-this.arrowHeight,
            "L",
            (this.width/2)+(this.arrowWidth/2), this.height-this.arrowHeight,
            "L",
            this.width/2, this.height,
            "L",
            (this.width/2)-(this.arrowWidth/2), this.height-this.arrowHeight, 
            "Z"
        ];


    };

    sponsorBubble.prototype.getFrame = function(frame, total_steps, current_step) {

    if (this.keypaths[frame + 1]) { //IF THERES FRAMES AFTER
        for (var i = 0; i <= this.keypaths[frame].length; i++) {
            //IF IS A LETTER
            if (isNaN(this.keypaths[frame][i])) {
                if (this.newpath && i < this.keypaths[frame].length - 1) {
                    this.newpath = this.newpath + this.keypaths[frame][i];
                }
                else if (!this.newpath) {
                    this.newpath = this.keypaths[frame][i];
                }
                else if (this.newpath && i == this.keypaths[frame].length - 1) {
                    this.newpath = this.newpath + this.keypaths[frame][i];
                }
            }

            //IF IS A NUMBER
            else {
                if (this.newpath && i < this.keypaths[frame].length - 1) {
                    this.newpath = this.newpath + (((this.keypaths[frame + 1][i] - this.keypaths[frame][i]) / total_steps) * current_step) + ", ";
                }
                else {
                    this.newpath = this.newpath + this.keypaths[frame][i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    else { //NO FRAMES AFTER
        for (var i = 0; i <= this.keypaths[frame].length; i++) {
            //IF IS A LETTER
            if (isNaN(this.keypaths[frame][i])) {
                if (this.newpath && i < this.keypaths[frame].length - 1) {
                    this.newpath = this.newpath + this.keypaths[frame][i];
                }
                else if (!this.newpath) {
                    this.newpath = this.keypaths[frame][i];
                }
                else if (this.newpath && i === this.keypaths[frame].length - 1) {
                    this.newpath = this.newpath + this.keypaths[frame][i];
                }
            }

            //IF IS A NUMBER
            else {
                if (this.newpath && i < this.keypaths[frame].length - 1) {
                    this.newpath = this.newpath + this.keypaths[frame][i] + ", ";
                }
                else {
                    this.newpath = this.newpath + this.keypaths[frame][i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

        current_step++;

        if (current_step < total_steps) {
                console.log(this.newpath);
            requestAnimationFrame(function() {
                bub.getFrame(frame, total_steps, current_step);
            });
        }
}

snapper = Snap('#svg');
var bub = new sponsorBubble($('#svg'), 'test', 5, 20);
bub.getFrame(0, 30, 0);

var test = snapper.path(bub.newpath);
    test.attr({
        fill: 'white',
        stroke: 'black'
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="bubble.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="snap.svg-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="bubble.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="inset">
            <div id="inset2">
                <svg id="svg" width="100%" height="100%"></svg>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#inset {
 width: 20%;
 height: 50%;
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 50%;
}

#inset2 {
 width: 80%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

JSfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/bmjkz1rf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpolation algorithm is wrong.

To interpolate between two values `x0` and `x1`, the formula is :

```
x0 + ((x1 - x0) * current_step / total_steps)
```

The code is currently missing the first `x0` term.

I think there's more to fix. As it stands, `this.newpath` is a string that grows and grows as the recursion progresses, without any delineation after "Z" and before the next "M". I don't know exactly what is required but I don't think that can be correct. Even if you fix the "...ZM..." delineation, you still end up with one monster string, whereas I guess you want a set (an array?) of individual frames.

Even if I'm wrong and you do want a monster string, it would be better to ditch `.getFrame()`'s recursion and call it iteratively, returning a single frame's worth of data at each iteration, and thus build your final data structure in the calling function.

Comment: Oh wow you're right. Didn't even notice that. And the idea was to call each frame iteratively, I just didn't realize it was adding rather than replacing the path data. Either way, thanks a lot man

Comment: I'm assuming your case needs something else, but thought I would mention that Snap will already morph between paths of the same number of points, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987836/how-to-animate-path-morphs-using-snap-svg

Comment: @Ian, nice one! As you can probably tell, I don't know much about SVG. I just debugged this from general knowledge of javaScript and simple mathematics.